# Derivative of vectorized kronecker product

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, kronecker-product

I'm struggling with the following derivative. Let $\pmb{X}$ be a symmetrical $n \times n$ matrix,  $\pmb{x} = \mathrm{vec}(\pmb{X})$ and let function $\pmb{f}$ take the following form:
$$
\pmb{f} = \mathrm{vec}\left( \pmb{X} \otimes \pmb{I}_n \right)
$$
This is part of a vectorized Jacobian for which I am trying to derive a Hessian. I want to find a solution for:
$$
\frac{\partial \pmb{f}}{\partial \pmb{x}}
$$
I recognized that there is some $n^4 \times n^2$ matrix $\pmb{Y}$, likely containing only zeroes and ones, such that:
$$
\mathrm{vec}\left( \pmb{X} \otimes \pmb{I}_n \right) = \pmb{Y} \pmb{x},
$$
as $\pmb{f}$ just contains only the elements of $\pmb{x}$ multiple times including a lot of zeroes. This would automatically imply:
$$
\frac{\partial \pmb{f}}{\partial \pmb{x}} = \pmb{Y}
$$
However, I can't think of a logical structure for $\pmb{Y}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let {$e_k$} be the standard vector basis, or if you prefer, the columns of $I_n$.

Then
$$\eqalign{
M &= \pmatrix{I_n\otimes e_1\cr I_n\otimes e_2\cr \vdots \cr I_n\otimes e_n} \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = Y &= \Big(I_n\otimes M\Big) \cr
}$$
A related problem is
$$\eqalign{
g &= {\rm vec}(I_n\otimes X) \cr
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} &= \Big(M\otimes I_n\Big) \cr
}$$

### Update

Using a [Commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix) provides the compact expression
$$M = \big(K^{(n,n)}\otimes I_n \big)\:\big(I_n\otimes{\rm vec}(I_n)\big)$$

Comment: Of course.. Thanks!